# Is there an English Bible translation that includes all of these books?

Tags: bible-translation, canon

Apostolic Constitutions Bk. 8. XLVII

Let the following books be esteemed venerable and holy by you, both of the clergy and laity. Of the Old Covenant: the five books of Moses— Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, and Deuteronomy; one of Joshua the son of Nun, one of the Judges, one of Ruth, four of the Kings, two of the Chronicles, two of Ezra, one of Esther, one of Judith, three of the Maccabees, one of Job, one hundred and fifty psalms; three books of Solomon— Proverbs, Ecclesiastes, and the Song of Songs; sixteen prophets. And besides these, take care that your young persons learn the Wisdom of the very learned Sirach. But our sacred books, that is, those of the New Covenant, are these: the four Gospels of Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John; the fourteen Epistles of Paul; two Epistles of Peter, three of John, one of James, one of Jude; two Epistles of Clement; and the Constitutions dedicated to you the bishops by me Clement, in eight books; which it is not fit to publish before all, because of the mysteries contained in them; and the Acts of us the Apostles. (Apostolic Canons 85.)

[An Early Biblical Canon](http://classicalchristianity.com/2011/09/13/an-early-biblical-canon/)

Comment: There are no Bible translations which include New Testament Apocrypha. Nevertheless, there are many English translations of the (Early) Church Fathers, where one might usually find these books. Personally, I use [Christian Classics Ethereal Library](http://www.ccel.org/fathers.html) and [New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers).

Comment: @Lucian: That is a good point, however, do you have any recommendations for which translations, in particular, would match well with any particular Bible translation? I'm just curious because usually, translations taken from different sources don't match very well, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I have no idea.